# How do I save weights for a keras model when I call fit multiple times?

Tags: python, keras

I want to save my model weights at certain intervals.

I have:

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('models/' + self._model_name + '.h5', period=10,
                                     monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True, mode='auto')
return self._model.fit(X, Y, epochs=50, verbose=0, callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

I call this function a few different times. It's a class, so the `self._model` remains across the different times I call it.

I one run, I get the output:

```
Epoch 00010: loss improved from inf to 9.95919, saving model to models/2019-04-07-23-02-16.h5

Epoch 00020: loss improved from 9.95919 to 7.46431, saving model to models/2019-04-07-23-02-16.h5

Epoch 00030: loss improved from 7.46431 to 5.46186, saving model to models/2019-04-07-23-02-16.h5

Epoch 00040: loss improved from 5.46186 to 4.57174, saving model to models/2019-04-07-23-02-16.h5

Epoch 00050: loss improved from 4.57174 to 3.75795, saving model to models/2019-04-07-23-02-16.h5
```

But then after that, I get:

```
Epoch 00010: loss improved from inf to 20.38285, saving model to models/2019-04-07-23-02-16.h5

Epoch 00020: loss improved from 20.38285 to 11.98181, saving model to models/2019-04-07-23-02-16.h5

Epoch 00030: loss did not improve from 11.98181

Epoch 00040: loss improved from 11.98181 to 10.54640, saving model to models/2019-04-07-23-02-16.h5

Epoch 00050: loss improved from 10.54640 to 6.20022, saving model to models/2019-04-07-23-02-16.h5
```

So why did it go back to `inf`? Shouldn't it keep `3.75795` as the lowest loss and therefore continue to use that as the checkpoint?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initiate checkpoint in each method call so its a new checkpoint and it starts from inf.
I know it seems a simple solution but I did it with a for loop. I needed to evaluate my model with some developed metrics, so I save weight, then evaluate it based on weights which are generated in each loop.

```
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="w1.h5", monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
for i in range(0,3):
    if(i >0):
        model.load_weights('weight'+str(i-1)+'.h5')

    model.fit(inputX,outputY , validation_data=(inputTestX,outputTest), batch_size=None, epochs=3, steps_per_epoch=200,validation_steps=200, callbacks=[checkpointer])         
    model.save_weights('model'+str(i)+'.h5')
    evaluate(i)
```

It works and produce such logs. As you can see it does not go back ti `inf` and it continues training.

```
Epoch 1/3
98/98 [==============================] - 14s 145ms/step - loss: 14.2190 - acc: 0.0110 - val_loss: 13.9000 - val_acc: 0.0000e+003s - loss: 14.5255 - acc: 0.0126
Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 13.89997, saving model to oldData/main/result/GCN-fullgraph-w1.h5
Epoch 2/3
98/98 [==============================] - 5s 46ms/step - loss: 13.8863 - acc: 0.0128 - val_loss: 13.5243 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 00002: val_loss improved from 13.89997 to 13.52433, saving model to oldData/main/result/GCN-fullgraph-w1.h5
Epoch 3/3
98/98 [==============================] - 4s 39ms/step - loss: 13.5929 - acc: 0.0135 - val_loss: 13.2898 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 00003: val_loss improved from 13.52433 to 13.28980, saving model to oldData/main/result/GCN-fullgraph-w1.h5
0.6165177671418206
0.6264390563241374

Epoch 1/3
98/98 [==============================] - 6s 58ms/step - loss: 13.2707 - acc: 0.0156 - val_loss: 12.9703 - val_acc: 0.0027
Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from 13.28980 to 12.97031, saving model to oldData/main/result/GCN-fullgraph-w1.h5
Epoch 2/3
98/98 [==============================] - 7s 72ms/step - loss: 12.8552 - acc: 0.0175 - val_loss: 12.6153 - val_acc: 0.0035
Epoch 00002: val_loss improved from 12.97031 to 12.61535, saving model to oldData/main/result/GCN-fullgraph-w1.h5
Epoch 3/3
98/98 [==============================] - 5s 55ms/step - loss: 12.5612 - acc: 0.0194 - val_loss: 12.2473 - val_acc: 0.0049
Epoch 00003: val_loss improved from 12.61535 to 12.24730, saving model to oldData/main/result/GCN-fullgraph-w1.h5
0.638404356344817
0.6429751200231312
```

If I put checkpoint inside for loop, I get this result, which starts from inf:

```
Epoch 1/3
98/98 [==============================] - 14s 145ms/step - loss: 14.2190 - acc: 0.0110 - val_loss: 13.9000 - val_acc: 0.0000e+003s - loss: 14.5255 - acc: 0.0126
Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 13.54957, saving model to oldData/main/result/GCN-fullgraph-w1.h5
Epoch 2/3
98/98 [==============================] - 5s 46ms/step - loss: 13.8863 - acc: 0.0128 - val_loss: 13.5243 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 00002: val_loss improved from 13.54957 to 13.22187, saving model to oldData/main/result/GCN-fullgraph-w1.h5
Epoch 3/3
98/98 [==============================] - 4s 39ms/step - loss: 13.5929 - acc: 0.0135 - val_loss: 13.2898 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 00003: val_loss improved from 13.22187 to 13.105615, saving model to oldData/main/result/GCN-fullgraph-w1.h5
0.6165177671418206
0.6264390563241374

Epoch 1/3
98/98 [==============================] - 6s 58ms/step - loss: 13.2707 - acc: 0.0156 - val_loss: 12.9703 - val_acc: 0.0027
Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 13.97031, saving model to oldData/main/result/GCN-fullgraph-w1.h5
Epoch 2/3
98/98 [==============================] - 7s 72ms/step - loss: 12.8552 - acc: 0.0175 - val_loss: 12.6153 - val_acc: 0.0035
Epoch 00002: val_loss improved from 13.97031 to 12.86802, saving model to oldData/main/result/GCN-fullgraph-w1.h5
Epoch 3/3
98/98 [==============================] - 5s 55ms/step - loss: 12.5612 - acc: 0.0194 - val_loss: 12.2473 - val_acc: 0.0049
Epoch 00003: val_loss improved from 12.86802 to 12.23080, saving model to oldData/main/result/GCN-fullgraph-w1.h5
0.638404356344817
0.6429751200231312
```

Comment: If it’s the same model, why do you have to save and load weights each time? Won’t they be saved with the model itself? Also, good call on the checkpoint being instantiated in the loop. That fixed it for me.

Comment: I evaluate the model in a different function. In that function I load the saved model and the saved weights. The model file does not contain weight matrix. It's a JSon file which describes the structure of your model, your layers, shape,...